# How to create a func so that it checks for the presence of columns in a df and returns a df with a new col?

Tags: python, pandas, function, csv, if-statement

I have a function in which I am trying to do the following:

1. Read in a csv (if it exists)
2. Check for presence of a column and return the dataframe if it exists.
3. If not, return None.

This function is below.

```
def func(id):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(path, low_memory=False)
        df["id"] = id
        if "column_1" not in df:
            return None
        else:
            return df
    except:
        return None
```

I want to modify this function so that if the first column of interest is not present, we check for another column and use that instead and then return the dataframe. This is what I have so far:

```
def func(id):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(path, low_memory=False)
        df["id"] = id
        if "column_1" not in df:
            if "column_2" not in df:
                return None
            else:
                df["new_col"] = df["column_2"]
                df = df.drop(["column_2"], axis=1)
                return df
        else:
            df["new_col"] = df["column_1"]
            df = df.drop(["column_1", "column_2"], axis=1)
            return df
    except:
        return None
```

I am not sure if this is correct and was hoping someone with a more expert eye could advise?

Comment: I think you can use a loop iterating within `df.columns` for the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is great and I believe it would do what you have asked. I'm suggesting another approach which I think is more easy to read because it checks for positive condition and not negative, but it might be a personal flavor:

```py
def func(id):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(path, low_memory=False)
        df["id"] = id
        if "column_1" in df.columns:
            df["new_col"] = df["column_1"]
            df = df.drop(["column_1"], axis=1)
            if "column_2" in df.columns:
                df = df.drop(["column_2"], axis=1)
        elif "column_2" in df.columns:
            df["new_col"] = df["column_2"]
            df = df.drop(["column_2"], axis=1)
        else:
            return None
    except:
        return None
```